# Добавление записи с проверкой на id

Tags: php, mysqli

Доброго времени суток.

Подскажите как правильно проверить на наличие `ID`? Нужно добавить запись, если `id` уже есть в наличии, вставляем с другим или добавляем +1. То есть нужно записать или вставить по любому, но `id` уникальный должно быть!

Comment: сделайте id auto_increment и вообще в insert его не используйте, или делайте NULL, БД в этом случае сама назначит уникальный ID

Comment: у меня просто нужно что бы в несколько таблиц добавлялся одинаковый id , что бы не в каждую разный пихало постоянно.
Тоесть есть id новости, ее нужно вставить в 5 таблиц, с данными и в 5 разных запросов

Comment: Вставляете NULL в первую таблицу, где он собственно уникальный, получаете только что вставленный id с помощью mysqli_insert_id() и используете в последующих запросах

Comment: Перед циклом вставить или уже в самом цикле?

Comment: смотря что делает цикл. не видя кода сказать ничего нельзя